# intregration without substitution of $x^x \ln x$

Tags: integration

How do i integrate this without any substitution, purely algebraically :

$$x^x \ln ex$$

I've tried a lot but not have been able to:

$$x^x \ (ln x + 1) = \ln x^{x^x} + x^x$$

or $e^{x \ln x}\ln (x+1)$, i've tried all these methods

How do proceed after this?

Comment: Write using LaTeX, otherwise it's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: I dont know how to

Comment: You're a member already six months and have posted 4 questions. I'd say it's about time you learn how.

Comment: compute the first derivative of $x^x$

Comment: I know that this is the derivative of x^x, i want to know how to integrate above form to x^x

Comment: $x^x \log(ex) = x^x(1 + \log x) = x^x (x\log x)' = x^x (\log x^x)' = (x^x)'$

Comment: @user3397 $(\log f(x))' = \frac{f(x)'}{f(x)}$. So $x^x(\log x^x)' = x^x \frac{(x^x)'}{x^x} = (x^x)'$.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks!

Comment: @questioner done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment turned into answer per request.

Notice 
$$x^x \log(ex) = x^x(1 + \log x) = x^x (x\log x)' = x^x (\log x^x)' = 
x^x \frac{(x^x)'}{x^x} = (x^x)'$$

We have

$$\int x^x \log(ex) dx = \int d(x^x) = x^x + \text{constant.}$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $y=x^x$, then
$$\ln y=x\ln x\implies \frac{y'}{y}=\ln x+1\\ y'=x^x(\ln x+1)=x^x\ln(ex)$$then
$$\int x^x\ln(ex)=y+c=x^x+c$$